# Is there any research about the number of people potentially affected by voting bills?

Tags: united-states, voting, demographics, poverty

I've read that [Texas and some other states](https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/research-reports/voting-laws-roundup-may-2021) are passing restrictive voting laws. Citation from [Texas Tribune](https://www.texastribune.org/2021/07/13/voting-bill-texas-senate/):

> The bill includes proposals to ban drive-thru and 24-hour voting options like those employed by Harris County in the last election to drive record-breaking numbers to the polls, and enhances access for partisan poll watchers. The bill also prohibits local election officials from sending out unsolicited applications to request mail-in ballots. It also includes new voter identification requirements for absentee voters.

But Kamala Harris stated in a CBS interview, that some restrictions would make voting more difficult in some counties and poorer districts in cities. Though, I cannot find original source, [here](https://nypost.com/2021/07/10/kamala-harris-slammed-for-saying-voter-id-laws-wouldnt-work-for-rural-voters/) are citations:

> I don’t think that we should underestimate what that could mean, because, in some people’s mind, that means, well, you’re going to have to Xerox or photocopy your ID to send it in to prove that you are who you are There are a whole lot of people, especially people who live in rural communities, who don’t — there’s no Kinko’s, there’s no Office Max near them

Is there an estimated number of poor people in the US affected by such voting restrictions?

Comment: A citation for the Harris statement would be useful to clarify that sentence.

Comment: @RickSmith, I've added, but not from CBS (in fact, added one citating CBS) - can't find

Comment: Awfully broad question. I mean hypothetically, everyone is affected by not get unsolicited applications ... Are you asking about Texas only?

Comment: The answer to the title question is "yes", but of course, finding citations to that research is much more involved and time consuming to write a real answer for.